# use DateTimePicker on aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a Form project that use DateTimePicker and I have to include those components into asp.net aspx webapp.
So I'm trying to include a DateTime Picker on asp.net webform but I can't.

I'm not an expert with aspx so maybe it's really a simple question.

I only see calendar in toolbox but not DateTimePicker.

The one I want to use is

```
System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
```

could it be possible to include it into asp.net project?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below on the Calender Click Method:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(calendar.SelectedDate.ToString());
```

Here calendar is the ID of your calendar control!

Hope this helps.

Comment: no, I want the datepicker UI element, not the calendar neither textbox

Answer (score 0):

Because it'is a web application i could just use JQuery UI
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display inline</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server" id="form1">
    Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a full API description http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/
May be this can help you as an alternative to do this also !\

There is also an Ajax library for .NET. you can try also: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/407460/How-to-use-ASP-NET-AJAX-Calender-Extender

Comment: I knew that, it doesn't respond to my question... but thanks :-)

Comment: I like Jquery for web, but i know there is an Ajax library for  .NET [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) . May be you can try it to your application. With good configuration i could help. Me i never used it but, you can try also.

Comment: My question was is it possible to use  System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker and if yes, how, I never talk about using similar component but thanks again :-)

Comment: I really don't know but i think that the Namespace System.Windows can be use only in windows application !!! and System.Windows.Forms in Windows Forms application. But you are doing ASP.NET WebForms application.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking it on stackoverflow